# biblatex is not working correctly

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I've been trying many options for my citations and references. I used `natbib` package and `plainnat` style, but I discovered `biblatex` and it seems better for customizing citations and bibligraphy styles. My problem is that I can't make it works.

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} 
\addbibresource{C:/Users/usuario/Documents/6_Latex_Files/References}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\begin{document}
Hi \parencite[i.e.][page 2]{Alamri2010}\\

Another citation \parencite{Bouvy1999,Ho2008,Ho2012c}\\

In line citation \parencite{Bar-Yosef2010}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Why the citations are not correct?

Why the pre and postnotes is not appearing?

Why the bibliography is naor appearing?

Observation (if helps): When I compile appears the following messages:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6200 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: document.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file document.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file document.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file document.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

Comment: biblatex files should be run with biber.

Comment: @TeXnician What is biber (sorry, I'm new in biblatex)?, how can I run biber?

Comment: This is  the default with `biblatex`. Did you run the normal cycle `pdflatex->bibtex or biber->pdflatex (twice)`?

Comment: @DanielValencia `biber` is the sorting program for `biblatex` analogous to `bibtex`, you would be run `biber` instead of `bibtex`.

Comment: Please follow the link I've posted. There is described how you should compile and why.

Comment: The details for how to run `biber` will depend on the editor you use, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations for instructions for some popular LaTeX editors.

Answer (score 0):

The following instruction is almost certainly at fault:

```
\addbibresource{C:/Users/usuario/Documents/6_Latex_Files/References}
```

The `\addbibresource` directive requires that users provide the filename extension -- most likely ".bib", right? Unlike BibTeX, which only looks for files with filename extension `.bib` for bibliographic entries, `biblatex` and the `\addbibresource` are much flexible in the file types that can be parsed. The "downside", if you will, is that the filename extension *must* be stated explicitly.

Thus, you should write

```
\addbibresource{C:/Users/usuario/Documents/6_Latex_Files/References.bib}
```

and recompile. Naturally, if the bib is *not* located in the directory `C:/Users/usuario/Documents/6_Latex_Files`, you should correct the argument of `\addbibresource` suitably.

---

Here's a full MWE (minimum working example). Be sure to run LaTeX, biber, and LaTeX once more to compile it.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
%% Create some dummy bib entries in a file called "References.bib"
\begin{filecontents}{References.bib}
@misc{Alamri2010,author="Alamri",title="AA",year=2010}
@misc{Bouvy1999, author="Bouvy", title="BB",year=1999}
@misc{Ho2008,    author="Ho",    title="CC",year=2008}
@misc{Ho2012c,   author="Ho",    title="DD",year=2012}
@misc{Bar-Yosef2010,author="Bar-Yosef",title="EE",year=2010}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,
            bibstyle=authortitle,
            backend=biber] % or: "backend=bibtex"
           {biblatex} 
\addbibresource{References.bib} % note the ".bib" extension

\begin{document}
Hi \parencite[i.e.,][page~2]{Alamri2010}

Another citation \parencite{Bouvy1999,Ho2008,Ho2012c}

Inline citation \parencite{Bar-Yosef2010}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```